# How many ways to glue a $4n$-gon to a genus $n$ surface?

Tags: combinatorics, general-topology, algebraic-topology, polygons

In this question :
[Two Fundamental Polygons for the Double Torus?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3341729/two-fundamental-polygons-for-the-double-torus)

Lee Mosher says

> There are four octagon gluing patterns (up to rotation and relabelling) which give a double torus.

It is a very interesting result to me, which makes me think about the following question.

> How may patterns (up to rotation and relabelling) to glue a $4n$-gon to a genus $n$ surface?

I tried to find all above patterns for a $12$-gon and I failed, since there are too many possibilities.

I feel like my problem is a natural one, so I'd love to know if it's already been solved.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://oeis.org/A291371. (I don't know what a chord diagram is, just went through OEIS entries that have the word genus and start 1, 4, ...)

Comment: @ronno Thank you so much. That is exactly what I want to know. I also want to thank you for letting me know about this interesting website OEIS.